# Delete/Clear Firebase Test Lab matrices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I cannot see any documentation or question on how to remove/clear matrices in Firebase Test Lab. I tried to delete the bucket but that only deletes the uploaded files such as APK and robo script as well as the test result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no way to clear test outcomes for past matrices in Firebase Test Lab. A complete history is kept in a database, but there is no charge for that data.

If you're using a custom (paid) results bucket instead of the free bucket supplied to every Firebase project, emptying that bucket will reduce Cloud Storage charges.

Comment: Is there any future plan for this to be implemented?

Comment: I'll file an internal feature request for this, but to date it hasn't been a high priority to implement.